# Order results witin search.php by custom meta field

Tags: php, search, plugins, wordpress

I need some help with ordering the results within search.php

If I search for the keyword "XYZ", by default it returns posts that have "XYZ" within the title, which is great.

As an example, let say I get the following results:
XYZ1
XYZ2
XYZ3

However, I want to sort those 3 results by a custom meta field called "priority"

so the above should look like this
XYZ2 (has priority 10)
XYZ1 (has priority 7)
XYZ3 (has priority 4)

I tried the following:

```
<?php
    $args = array(
    'orderby'   => 'meta_value_num',
    'meta_key'  => 'priority',
    'order'     => 'DESC'
);
query_posts($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    // Results
endwhile;
?>
```

But what I get in return are irrelevant posts ordered by priority, for example
XYZ2 (has priority 10)
ABC3 (has priority 9)
BBA4 (has priority 8)
XYZ1 (has priority 7)
... and so on

No sure if I'm missing something.

---

I also tried this:

```
<?php
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_search) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('meta_key', 'priority' );
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set('order', 'DESC' );
    }
    return $query;
}

add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
?>
```

---

Here's the final code snippet that worked for me.

```
<?php
function SearchFilter($query) {
    if ($query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()) {
        $query->set('post_type', 'post');
        $query->set('showposts', -1);
        $query->set('meta_key', 'priority' );
        $query->set('orderby', 'meta_value_num' );
        $query->set('order', 'DESC' );
    }
    return $query;
}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
?>
```

Comment: Try setting it using `pre_get_posts` function, it should help

Comment: i just tried the another code, but still the same wrong result... the code is above

Comment: try using `query->is_main_query() && $query->is_search()` in if condition

Comment: @VaibhavBhanushali , thanks that solved my issue, I've posted the final code in my original comment.

Comment: Great, that it helped, but where is the final code?

Comment: Great question. I'm going to be doing the same thing with woocommerce products. just to be clear -- `meta_value_num` is a custom meta field associated with posts? did you end up setting a max ( 100 ) or something for this? also where did this code end up? search.php or functions? thanks.

Comment: were you able to set default values?  this works for me, but only if each post has a value set.

Answer (score 0):

How about the snippets following?

```
    if (get_query_var('paged'))
      $paged = get_query_var('paged');
    elseif (get_query_var('page'))
      $paged = get_query_var('page');
    else
      $paged = 1;

    $s = get_query_var('s');

    $args = array(
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => 'priority',
        'order' => 'DESC',
        'paged' => $paged,
        's' => $s,
        'post_type' => array('post'),
    );

    query_posts($args);
```